# Google Nearby Connections API (iOS, Android)

Tags: android, ios, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

We are trying to use Google's Nearby Connections API for Android and iOS:
https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview
and in the description it's saying: "The Nearby Connections API is available for Android and iOS, and enables communication between the two platforms."
Does anyone who already used this framework, and were able to make communication between the 2 platform? as of 2023 Dec, it seems that it's still not working.

we were able to communicate beetween

Android <> Android

iOS <> iOS

But it's not working between iOS <> Android.

We are using the samep service id, setted up properly the info.plist on the iOS side *generated the tcp service name from the service id. (generated here: https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/swift/get-started)

what else we should setup to communicate between the 2 platforms? any idea?

Comment: I don't see the quote about interoperability at the referenced link, do you have another reference? Would be great if it worked.

Comment: its here: https://developers.google.com/nearby under the Nearby Connections API

Answer (score 1):

iOS <> Android should work as long as the service IDs match and both devices are connected to the same Wi-Fi network. It should definitely work with the "Point-to-Point" strategy, but I haven't personally tested "Cluster" or "Star", so not sure if those work.

Comment: yes you are right, there is a way if its working, which is not a real life scenario imho. 
iOS has to be the hotspot, every android phone should connect to the iPhone with WiFi. and then its working...

Comment: @szuniverse maybe consider creating a report on the issuetracker, with Nearby Messages API gone they may be motivated to get it working better.